# Styling materialize select with materialize from angular 2 materialize directive

Tags: css, angular, sass, materialize

I'm trying to style the input field of the select box that materialize css creates. I'm using the angular 2 materialize directive. This is what my html looks like:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select id="property-selector" materialize="material_select" name="propertySelector">
    <option class="property-option">Address 1, 1000AA Amsterdam, The Netherlands</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

This is what the scss looks like:

```
#property-selector-card {
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #118073;
  font-size: 17pt;
  div.select-wrapper {
    .select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
      border-bottom: none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

This generates the following html in the browser:

```
<div _ngcontent-kld-6="" class="card-panel row" id="property-selector-card">
  <div _ngcontent-kld-6="" class="input-field col s12">
    <div class="select-wrapper initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span>
      <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data-activates="select-options-95a42e27-1c84-d800-0534-aaaaeb70c462" value="Address 1, 1000AA Amsterdam, The Netherlands"><ul id="select-options-95a42e27-1c84-d800-0534-aaaaeb70c462" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown "><li class=""><span>Address 1, 1000AA Amsterdam, The Netherlands</span></li></ul>
      <select _ngcontent-kld-6="" id="property-selector" materialize="material_select" name="propertySelector" ng-reflect-materialize="material_select" class="initialized"
        <option _ngcontent-kld-6="" class="property-option">Address 1, 1000AA Amsterdam, The Netherlands</option>
      </select></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'm having issues overriding the border-bottom style (that I don't want). The selector that I use in scss does not seem to respond.

I've been able to adjust the font by setting it on a parent element, but I get stuck with the select-wrapper element that the materialize js generates and the css selector I use gets overriden as well it seems.

Any idea how to effectively style the input element?

Comment: You got any working solution. I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. In my case, I was trying to add the style in the component.style.css file and it did not have any effect, then I tried by adding it to main **style.css** and it worked.

I think in your case, instead of using id, use class name to traverse through and set style.

```
.custom-select {
  div.select-wrapper {
    .select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
      border-bottom: none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

and give the classname to the outermost div of select element

```
<div class="input-field col s12 custom-select">
  <select id="property-selector" materialize="material_select" name="propertySelector">
    <option class="property-option">Address 1, 1000AA Amsterdam, The Netherlands</option>
  </select>
</div>
```